# Google Maps API and administrative areas in Finland

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a product that performs geocode lookups for user-inputted addresses. The code assumes that results should contain a `administrative_area_level_1` which translates into a `state` and `stateCode` (I know the documentation states that not all nations use this, but this is how the code was written before me.). We're seeing an issue in production with Finland addresses and I started poking around the documentation on the developers site and found something interesting.

On this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

They list an example lookup in Finland:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=route:Annegatan|administrative_area:Helsinki|country:Finland

For that lookup, they list a sample reply that contains:

```
{
  "long_name" : "Helsingfors",
  "short_name" : "Helsingfors",
  "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
}
```

However, if you actually load that url, this is what it says for that part of the address:

```
{
  "long_name" : "Helsingfors",
  "short_name" : "H:fors",
  "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
},
```

Did something change with this?

Thanks

Comment: The geocoder just went through a major rewrite/update.  See https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/11/address-geocoding-in-google-maps-apis.html

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is to draw the third administrative level in addition to the geocoded point, I guess you already have their boundaries stored somewhere.

To deal with variations in long_name or short_name you'll need to make yourself a dictionary that, for example, translates "H:fors" to "Helsignfors". And that is a job that might take some time, but it is also iterative. You'll need to record occurences of google describing a short name that you don't have in your DB, then edit your dictionary accordingly.